# Fluent NHibernate, auto mapper projections cannot be converted to type System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Object[]]

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, automapper, projection

Having an odd issue with auto mapper projections.  I have the following entities:

```
public class BankEntity
{
    public BankEntity()
    {
        Customers = new List<CustomerEntity>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public IList<CustomerEntity> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerEntity
{
    public CustomerEntity()
    {
        Accounts = new List<BankAccountEntity>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<BankAccountEntity> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class BankAccountEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

using the following views:

```
public class BankView
{
    public BankView()
    {
        Customers = new List<CustomerView>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<CustomerView> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

with the following view mappings:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<BankEntity, BankView>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerEntity, CustomerView>();
```

I have a repo object that wraps the nhibernate session.  When using the following:

```
_repoContext.First<BankEntity, BankView>(a => true);
```

I get the following error:

```
Object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[ExampleApp.BankView]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Object[]]'.
```

The First method is:

```
public TP First<TE, TP>(Expression<Func<TE, bool>> exp)
{
    return Session.Query<TE>().Where(exp).Project().To<TP>().AsQueryable().First();
}
```

If I do not have a child list (i.e. the Customers in BankView) it will return just fine.

I added the AsQueryable to try and avoid this issue.  I can't figure out why it wont map the child list of CustomerViews.

**EDIT**

stack trace:

```
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at NHibernateRepo.Repos.RepoSplit`2.First[TE,TP](Expression`1 exp) in d:\Development\NHibernateRepoProject\NHibernateRepo\Repos\Repo.cs:line 117
```

nhibernate SQL output:

```
NHibernate: select customers1_.Id as col_0_0_, customers1_.Id as col_1_0_, customers1_.Name as col_2_0_, bankentity0_.Id as col_3_0_, bankentity0_.Id as col_4_0_, bankentity0_.Name as col_5_0_ from [BankEntity] bankentity0_ left outer join [CustomerEntity] customers1_ on bankentity0_.Id=customers1_.BankEntity_id where @p0=1 ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;@p0 = True [Type: Boolean (0)]
```

**EDIT 2**

As an idea I have added the bankAccountEntity to the view, so the updated views look like:

```
public class BankView
{
    public BankView()
    {
        Customers = new List<CustomerView>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<CustomerView> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerView
{
    public CustomerView()
    {
        Accounts = new List<BankAccountView>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<BankAccountView> Accounts { get; set; }

}

public class BankAccountView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
}
```

The exception I get how has changed:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Code supposed to be unreachable
```

with a stack trace of:

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.MemberAssignmentRewriter..ctor(MemberAssignment binding, StackSpiller spiller, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.BindingRewriter.Create(MemberBinding binding, StackSpiller spiller, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMemberInitExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLambdaExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.MemberAssignmentRewriter..ctor(MemberAssignment binding, StackSpiller spiller, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.BindingRewriter.Create(MemberBinding binding, StackSpiller spiller, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMemberInitExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLambdaExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteInvocationExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile()
at NHibernate.Linq.ExpressionToHqlTranslationResults.MergeLambdasAndCompile[TDelegate](IList`1 itemTransformers)
at NHibernate.Linq.ExpressionToHqlTranslationResults..ctor(HqlTreeNode statement, IList`1 itemTransformers, IList`1 listTransformers, IList`1 postExecuteTransformers, List`1 additionalCriteria)
at NHibernate.Linq.IntermediateHqlTree.GetTranslation()
at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Boolean filter)
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan.CreateTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan..ctor(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
at NHibernateRepo.Repos.RepoSplit`2.First[TE,TP](Expression`1 exp) in d:\Development\NHibernateRepoProject\NHibernateRepo\Repos\Repo.cs:line 117
```

**EDIT 3**

```
var expression = AutoMapper.Mapper.Engine.CreateMapExpression(typeof (BankEntity), typeof (BankView));
```

Expression gives:

```
.New ExampleApp.BankView(){
Id = $dto.Id,
Name = $dto.Name,
Customers = .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(.Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(
        $dto.Customers,
        .Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[ExampleRepo.Models.CustomerEntity,ExampleApp.CustomerView]>))
}

.Lambda    #Lambda1<System.Func`2[ExampleRepo.Models.CustomerEntity,ExampleApp.CustomerView]>(ExampleRepo.Models.CustomerEntity $dto)
{
.New ExampleApp.CustomerView(){
    Id = $dto.Id,
    Name = $dto.Name,
    Accounts = .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(.Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(
            $dto.Accounts,
            .Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[ExampleRepo.Models.BankAccountEntity,ExampleApp.BankAccountView]>))
}
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[ExampleRepo.Models.BankAccountEntity,ExampleApp.BankAccountView]>(ExampleRepo.Models.BankAccountEntity $dto)
{
.New ExampleApp.BankAccountView(){
    Id = $dto.Id,
    Name = $dto.Name,
    Balance = $dto.Balance
}
}
```

**EDIT**

looks like it might be related to:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3043

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3356

Comment: What's the stack trace on the exception? (is it in AutoMapper or NH?)

Comment: Any better with an array rather than an `IList`? Or a different message?

Comment: exact same error message

Comment: Weird thing is it's saying it can't convert from a load of `BankView`s to a load of `object[]`s.  I.e. the one on the right is a collection of arrays (not objects)

Comment: Worth trying `Mapper.CreateMapExpression` to get AutoMapper to create the projection, and having a look at the `DebugView` of that expression.  Hopefully it includes code to map the child view type too.  If not, AM is the problem.  Could also try replacing `Project().To<TP>()` with `Select(projection)` (where projection is the expression)

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the expression

Comment: Looks OK to me too. My guess is something not supported by, or bug in, NHibernate.  Could get minimum repo by recreating your own Select() which maps the child ones without using automapper